# How to lock non-virtual terminal? Something like "vlock -a""

Tags: screen-lock, lock

There is an option with `vlock` to lock all `pts/tty` at a time which is,

```
$ vlock -a
```

But `vlock` can lock only virtual consoles.

There is also an option named `TMOUT` which will terminate the current sessions after given time.

So is there any tool to lock my all non-virtual terminal/pseudoterminal for terminal safety like `TMOUT` or `vlock -a`?

Answer (score 1):

The error tell you: you cannot vlock not-virtual terminal. This is by design of vlock, and it will be very difficult to really lock non-virtual terminal.

For the second question: just lock your screen (with a screensaver + password).